# Bash variable expansion with a '/'

Tags: bash, variable-expansion, parameter-expansion

Inside of a while read line loop, I see this variable expansion `${line/device name:}`. I've tried running the script with my own input file and it just prints out the line.

Can you tell me what that expansion is doing?

Comment: Both answers are correct, but here's the documentation on parameter expansions for later reference and editing into answers:  http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Answer (score 4):

The variable name is `line`. / is for string substitution, that is "device name:" if exists *anywhere* in the `$line` is removed.

```
> line="a device name: some name"
> echo ${line/device name:}
a  some name
```

You may also see `#` and `%` substitutions, which stand for substitutions in the `line` begin and end. Also beware that such `/` substitution is a bash-specific feature (e.g. `ash` doesn't support it, `%` and `#` are seemingly portable), so you should use `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/sh` as a hashbang in the beginning of your script.

Comment: `%` and `#` are indeed portable, being [part of the POSIX shell specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02).

Comment: Thank you.  Excellent answer!

Answer (score 3):

It returns `$line` with the substring `device name:` removed. From the bash man page:

```
${parameter/pattern/string}
       Pattern substitution.  The pattern is expanded to produce a pattern just as in
       pathname  expansion.   Parameter  is expanded and the longest match of pattern
       against its value is replaced with string.  If  pattern  begins  with  /,  all
       matches of pattern are replaced with string.  Normally only the first match is
       replaced.  If pattern begins with #, it must match at  the  beginning  of  the
       expanded  value  of parameter.  If pattern begins with %, it must match at the
       end of the expanded value of parameter.  If string is null, matches of pattern
       are  deleted and the / following pattern may be omitted.  If parameter is @ or
       *, the substitution operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn,
       and  the  expansion  is the resultant list.  If parameter is an array variable
       subscripted with @ or *, the substitution operation is applied to each  member
       of the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.
```

Comment: Thank you.  Excellent answer!